¿Cómo agregar llevadas y galeras en LaTeX?
¡Saludos!
Mi problema radica en agregar llevadas a las sumas y a las restas, es decir, poder representar las sumas y restas de forma vertical como se hace en la primaria.
De hecho, esa es la razón por la que quiero agregar llevadas; porque soy una tutora de matemáticas para niños de primaria.
También, me gustaría saber si se puede agregar la casita de la división o galera.
He estado buscando desde muchas páginas y tutoriales para poder agregar las llevadas y las galeras, pero no he tenido éxito. Creo, que es porque todavía soy novata (apenas aprendí usar LaTeX este lunes) pero ya he logrado realizar diferentes documentos con diferentes estilos; por eso sé que LaTeX es capaz de hacer eso y más.

Hola Luz100, bienvenida, te comento que en el sitio, se hecen y responden preguntas sobre el arte de programar, por lo que seguramente, tu pregunta será cerrada, por suerte ya recibiste una respuesta, pero te sugiero que para la proxima, recurras a sitios especializados en el tema, suerte!!

Para hacer operaciones aritméticas verticales, es muy útil el paquete xlop.
Por ejemplo, para hacer una suma en vertical:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}

\opadd{4825}{5307}

\end{document}

Para restas, debes utilizar el comando \opsub{}{}, para multiplicaciones \opmul{}{} y para divisiones \opdiv{}{} o \opidiv{}{} dependiendo de si quieres divisiones “normales” o euclidianas, respectivamente
Lamentablemente, el manual está disponible solamente en inglés.

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, solo que tengo una duda: ¿el paquete xlop solo genera las operaciones con resultados? Es que necesito agregar las sumas, restas, multiplicaciones y divisiones sin resultado. Lamento las molestias.

@Luz100, te dejaron una referencia al manual. Le dí una mirada y al final de la página 9, inicio de la 10, parece estar lo que buscas.
